# Как передать данные radiobutton ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html

Как передать данные radiobutton ссылке, которая будет выполнять действие?

```
<input type="radio" name="id" value='.($managers[$i]->id).' />
<li><a rel="mode" href="index.php?mode=user_del&id=' тут переданный ID' "><i class="icon-remove"></i> Удалить профиль </a></li>
<script>
    (function(){
        var actions = document.querySelectorAll('[rel="mode"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++)
        {
            actions[i].onclick = function(){
                var id = document.querySelector('[name="id"]:checked').value;
                location.href = this.href + '&id=' + id;
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

По идее данные с формы передаются по форме, но и на ссылку можно поставить обработчик

```
<form action="/actiontake" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="0"/>
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="1"/>
    <a href="#" onClick="submit()">click</a>
</form>
```

Есть второй способ, там через javascript надо будет менять href(ссылки) при клике

```
    <input type="radio" onClick="var el=document.getElementById('submiter');el.href='/actiontake.php?status=0'"/>
    <input type="radio" onClick="var el=document.getElementById('submiter');el.href='/actiontake.php?status=1'"/>
    <a href="#" id="submiter">click</a>
```

Как то так, за работоспособность не ручаюсь, писал вслепую.

Comment: можно без определения переменной сделать: 

onClick="document.getElementById('submiter').href='/actiontake.php?status=0'"